# Sorting array in drupal 7

Tags: arrays, sorting, drupal, drupal-7

I am a newbie in Drupal. Please accept my ignorance. I have a page with a custom hook to override the view and display list of posts with default sorting or no sorting. I want to sort the array based on the node create date. But not sure where to plug the sorting argument. Can anyone please help? I have this code block in my_view.module file.

```
    function _sites_by_park_page_get_node_references($fieldName, $property, $park_id) {
      $results = array();
      $parks = _sites_by_park_page_get_sites($park_id);
      foreach ($parks['features'] as $feature) {
        foreach($feature['properties'][$property] as $key => $value) {
          if (!array_key_exists($key, $results)) {
            $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
            $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node');
            $query->fieldCondition($fieldName, 'value', $value);
            $result = $query->execute();
            $node = node_load(array_shift(array_keys($result['node'])));
            $results[$key] = $node->title;
          }
        }
      }
      return $results;
    }

    /**
     * Return GeoJSON formatted park data
     */
    function _sites_by_park_page_get_sites($park_id) {
      // Uses a lot of memory thanks to views and GD image resizing, could use some garbage collection opimisation
      ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
      $data_view = views_get_view('sites_by_park_data');
      $data_view->set_arguments(array($park_id));
      $data_view->execute('page');

      // Build our own, more lightweight geojson structure for faster page loads (Leaflet module generated 2MB of data vs this custom module's 40kb-ish for 140 parks)
      $results = array(
        'type' => 'FeatureCollection',
        'features' => array(),
      );
      foreach($data_view->result as $result) {
        // Initialise some arrays that may be merged between result sets (for instance when multiple activities contribute to a site's overall data)
        if (!isset($results['features'][$result->nid])) {
          $results['features'][$result->nid] = array(
            'type' => 'Feature',
            'properties' => array()
          );
        }



  }   
  $results['features'] = array_values($results['features']);
  return $results;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you set ordering normal way, from view's admin page? Why you have to do that from code?

Comment: This was an excellent tip. For some reason, I didn't think about this. Thanks MilanG

Comment: Everything you can do from back-end - do form back-end. That's the point of using CMS. :)

Answer (score 0):

As per MilanG's suggestion I have done this through admin section. Change the sorting order and it works fine now.